# From Dataframe to Datestamp python3

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, timestamp

recently I faced a really weird csv file with 2 columns (with headers), one for dates and the second one for prices. The time format was "dd.mm.yyyy".

```
d = {'Date': [31.12.1991, 02.01.1992, 03.01.1992, 06.01.1992], 
     'Prices': [9.62, 9.5, 9.73, 9.45]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
prices = pd.DataFrame(df['Prices'])
date = pd.DataFrame(df['Date'])
date = date.to_string(header=True)
date = df.to_datetime(utc=True, infer_datetime_format=True)
frame = date.join(values)
print(df)
```

I tried to make it work by isolating the date column and trying to transform it first into string with the to_string() function and then back to date with the to_datetime but it was no use.

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to parse the dates when you read in the file. You can specify that the format has the day first instead of the month.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', parse_dates=['Date'], dayfirst=True)

print(df)
#        Date   Prices
#0 1991-12-31     9.62
#1 1992-01-02     9.50
#2 1992-01-03     9.73
#3 1992-01-06     9.45

df.dtypes
#Date      datetime64[ns]
#Prices           float64
#dtype: object
```

However, your data really need to be clean and properly formatted for this to work:

> parse_dates:
>
> - If a column or index contains an unparseable date, **the entire column
>     or index will be returned unaltered as an object data type**. For
>     non-standard datetime parsing, use pd.to_datetime after pd.read_csv

---

Sample Data: test.csv

```
Date,Prices
31.12.1991,9.62
02.01.1992,9.5
03.01.1992,9.73
06.01.1992,9.45
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't consider that I could fix the issue by going back to the CSV =)

Answer (score 5):

#### Interesting way to generalize for whole dataframe

**Note** This uses `errors='ignore'` in order to skip columns that might not be suitable for parsing as dates.  However, the trade off is that if there is a column that is intended to be parsed as dates but has a bad date value, this approach will leave that column unaltered.  The point is to make sure you don't have bad date values.

```
df.assign(
    **df.select_dtypes(exclude=[np.number]).apply(
        pd.to_datetime, errors='ignore', dayfirst=True
    )
)

        Date  Prices
0 1991-12-31    9.62
1 1992-01-02    9.50
2 1992-01-03    9.73
3 1992-01-06    9.45
```

---

Another example

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    A=1, B='B', C='6.7.2018', D=1-1j,
    E='1.2.2017', F=pd.Timestamp('2016-08-08')
), [0])

df

   A  B         C       D         E          F
0  1  B  6.7.2018  (1-1j)  1.2.2017 2016-08-08
```

---

```
df.assign(
    **df.select_dtypes(exclude=[np.number]).apply(
        pd.to_datetime, errors='ignore', dayfirst=True
    )
)

   A  B          C       D          E          F
0  1  B 2018-07-06  (1-1j) 2017-02-01 2016-08-08
```

### Setup

borrowed from jezrael

```
d = {'Date': ['31.12.1991', '02.01.1992', '03.01.1992', '06.01.1992'], 
     'Prices': [9.62, 9.5, 9.73, 9.45]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Comment: Hmmm, `errors='ignore'` is not good idea if bad datetimes, maybe you can pointed need all valid dates.

Answer (score 3):

I believe need:

```
d = {'Date': ['31.12.1991', '02.01.1992', '03.01.1992', '06.01.1992'], 
     'Prices': [9.62, 9.5, 9.73, 9.45]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True)
print (df)
        Date  Prices
0 1991-12-31    9.62
1 1992-01-02    9.50
2 1992-01-03    9.73
3 1992-01-06    9.45
```